# Wrapping text field wants to be 1 line high despite constraints

Tags: xcode, cocoa, interface-builder

Here's what I do (in Xcode 7.3):

- Make a new view xib file
- Drag a "wrapping text field" into the view
- Resize it to be the standard 20 pixels away from each side of the parent view
- Open the pinning tool ("Add new constraints") and click all four red I-beam shapes to add a constraint for each side
- Click on "Add 4 Constraints"

The text field ends up outlined in orange, with a dotted orange rectangle showing it wants to be 1 line (22 pixels) high.

Clicking "Update constraints" does nothing. Clicking "Update frames" shrinks it down to 22 pixels high, but it's still orange because of course now it violates its top margin constraint.

Why does it want to be that height? The point of choosing a "wrapping text field" is I want it to be more than one line high.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrapping labels decide on the intrinsic content size based on the amount of text in them. If your placeholder string is say "Label", autolayout will give it one line's worth of space irrespective of how much bottom space you give it.

The correct way to use autolayout with wrapping labels is to not give it a fixed bottom constraint, but instead give it a greater or equal one. Say something like "V:|-5-[wrapping label]->=5-|" in VSL. Then, when you set the label's `stringValue`, it will be able to expand itself given the bottom constraint has an upperbound.

Comment: 1. This is for a text field, for user entry, not a text label. Does the same thing apply? I wouldn't have expected it. 2. Even for the label case, is there really no way to achieve this in Interface Builder? Makes me want to go back to the old rods and springs.

Comment: 1. Yup. Labels are NSTextFields in any case. 2. In IB, you set this to a bottom constraint and change the relation to greater or equal